# Printing Same string x times using python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7, count

Hello Stack Overflow,

More than likely there is a really simple solution for this problem.

```
    count1 = 12
    count2 = 15
    countdifference = count2 - count1

    if countdifference > 0:
        print selection
```

So the above code is self explanatory, however how can I amend this code to print selection x times, where x = the countdiffernce? In this instance it would be 15-12 which = 3, then it would print selection 3 times.

Any help or comments would be appreciated, kind regards AEA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print str(selection) * countdifference
```

or

```
for ii in xrange(countdifference):
    print selection
```

Comment: well that seems too simple, Ill give it a whirl :)

Comment: Or `range(count1, count2)`, eliminating the need to compute the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiplier operator:

```
print selection * countdifference
```

In python, when you have a string and you multiply that string it returns another string like this:

```
>>> test = "message"
>>> print test * 3
messagemessagemessage
```